# return back to previous activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i am doing a search results and once I click on the results, it will display the details. After I click on the back button, it should display the searched results I have done. 
E.g.

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I click "back" on image 3, it returned to image 1 instead of image 2. Is there a way to solve it? I simply just did finish(); on image 3

Comment: whats diff B/W image 1 & 2 here ?? both seems same to me

Comment: You need to maintain states by `boolean` which tells you that detail screen in via `search`.

Comment: @KalpeshLakhani sorry, i forgot to state the difference, the image 2 is after i have searched for something!

Comment: go through onActivityResult override method

Answer (score 0):

You need to intercept the back button and control the flow of your application. **DO NOT** use state variables, avoid this approach as this can lead to more unstable problem **UNLESS** you design your states very carefully and have your states defined **WELL**. Try to learn the control that is available in the android framework.

Comment: I don't think intercepting the back button will help. It's just that the state (search results) of the previous activity isn't saved and going back will reset the results of the search.

Comment: If you intercept it then it won't backtrack in the activities. Specifically it doesn't look like a new Activity that he/she wants. I believe he is using a view to display the content.

Comment: I am retrieving the company name from Search view then pass it to details view to display the other contents. I dont know if what I said helped. I don't really get what both of you are trying to say. Sorry!